# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 415 Error: Unsupported Media Type

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have created a proxy service in wso2, while try accessing the proxy service it shows error as Unsupported Media Type, but I have set Content-Type: application/xml .payload is in xml format, so am setting it to application/xml in the source view ,still am getting the same error, Please help me to resolve this issue

```
**Proxy Service:**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="test"
       transports="http,https"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="Content-Type" value="application/xml"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://192.35.72.369:8080/ESB_Services/DRAM/service/CreateCustomer"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>

**Payload:**
<customer>
    <name>admin</name>
    <email>admin@gmail.com</email>
    <mobile_number>9904324234</mobile_number>
    <address>Bangalore</address>
    <zipcode>574515</zipcode>
</customer>

**ERROR:**
<TryitProxyError h:status="SOAP envelope error" xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 415 Error: Unsupported Media Type</TryitProxyError>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to choose the appropriate messageFormatter, used to format a message going out from the ESB, you use the property 'messageType' : `<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" />`